# Can I edit login script

Tags: grub2, scripts

Can I edit login script? For I want to restrict the user to only have 3 login attempts. If the user fails to login in after 3 attempts, the system must shutdown.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

See file

```
/etc/pam.d/common-auth
```

This line should let someone have 3 attempts. It also unlocks after 21600 seconds (=6 hours).

```
auth required pam_tally.so onerr=fail deny=3 unlock_time=21600
```

This will not shut down your system but have the user stay at the login screen with a notice (s)he can not login. I have not yet see a method where you can shut the system down after 3 failed loging attempts.

Comment: sir (Rinzwind)After doing modification to the common-auth. My system goes into low graphics mode.then there is no choice rather than reinstall the system .Is there any valid tested method or script, that help me out.

Comment: where i can get the login script ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can shutdown the system from PAM. You need something where you can call your own custom script when the user fails to log in.

Take a look at [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), that looks like you can set up a custom action.

Comment: Sir actually i want it on single system.